how input string in adb shell command
I have command on bash:
adb shell '/bin/sh -c "CLASSPATH=\$(pm path androidx.test.services) app_process / androidx.test.services.shellexecutor.ShellMain am instrument -w --no-window-animation -e clearPackageData false -e annotation '$annotationsString' -e targetInstrumentation ru.hh.hhh.test/com.kaspersky.kaspresso.runner.KaspressoRunner androidx.test.orchestrator/.AndroidTestOrchestrator"'

When annotationsString is the string I got is like this:
IFS=','
annotationsString=''
read -ra annotations <<< "$MARATHON_ALLOW_ANNOTATIONS"

pos=$((${#annotations[*]} - 1))
last=${annotations[$pos]}

for annotation in "${annotations[@]}";
do
  annotationsString="${annotationsString}com.salute.tests.utils.${annotation}"
  if [[ $annotation != $last ]]
  then
    annotationsString="${annotationsString} "
  fi
done

annotationsString=$(echo ${annotationsString} | tr ' ' ',')

And this string equals:
com.hh.tests.utils.ONE_ANNOTATION,com.hh.tests.utils.TWO_ANNOTATION

but on output i have error:
adb shell '/bin/sh -c "CLASSPATH=\$(pm path androidx.test.services) app_process / androidx.test.services.shellexecutor.ShellMain am instrument -w --no-window-animation -e clearPackageData false -e annotation com.hh.tests.utils.ONE_ANNOTATION' 'com.hh.tests.utils.TWO_ANNOTATION -e targetInstrumentation ru.hh.hhh.test/com.kaspersky.kaspresso.runner.KaspressoRunner androidx.test.orchestrator/.AndroidTestOrchestrator"'

as you can see, there is no comma, but it appeared ' '
How I can input annotationsString with comma in bash command ?

Check your code at https://shellcheck.net . (Be sure to include #!/bin/bash (or other) as the first line).  If you find actionable changes to make, update your question with the corrected code.


IFS=','
adb shell 'blabla'$annotationsString'blabla'


You set IFS to comma and $annotationsString is not quoted, so the command is split on comma into two words on comma.

How I can input annotationsString with comma in bash command ?

You should quote the expansion adb shell 'blabla'"$annotationsString"'blabla'. You should check your scripts with shellcheck, which will detect such errors.

OK, my solution is to add a variable OIFS=$IFS
And latter use to reset IFS IFS=$OIFS

I would disagree, that is a workaround. The solution is to quote variable expansion. You can also reset IFS by unset-ing it or setting to nothing IFS=
